# How can I decode a utf-8 byte array to a string in Python2?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, utf-8

I have an array of bytes representing a utf-8 encoded string. I want to decode these bytes back into the string in Pyton2. I am relying on Python2 for my overall program, so I can not switch to Python3.

```
array = [67, 97, 102, **-61, -87**, 32, 70, 108, 111, 114, 97]
```

-> Caf**é** Flora

Since every character in the string I want is not necessarily represented by exactly 1 byte in the array, I can not use a solution like:

```
"".join(map(chr, array))
```

I tried to create a function that would step through the array, and whenever it encounters a number not in the range 0-127 (ASCII), create a new 16 bit int, shift the current bits over 8 to the left, and then add the following byte using a bitwise OR. Finally it would use unichr() to decode it.

```
result = []


for i in range(len(byte_array)):
    x = byte_array[i]
    if x < 0:
        b16 = x & 0xFFFF # 16 bit
        b16 = b16 << 8
        b16 = b16 | byte_array[i+1]
        result.append(unichr(m16))
    else:
        result.append(chr(x))

return "".join(result)
```

However, this was unsuccessful.

The following article explains the issue very well, and includes a nodeJS solution:

http://ixti.net/development/node.js/2011/10/26/get-utf-8-string-from-array-of-bytes-in-node-js.html

Comment: That is not how UTF-8 decoding works.

Comment: Can you not "pad" every number in the range of 0-128 with `00`?

Comment: As you can see inmy answer, your join with map and chr version almost works - but for the problem you have with negative numbers. My answer bellow is essentialy the same, using the more readable generator expression , and taking care of the negative numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `struct.pack` for this

```
>>> a =  [67, 97, 102, -61, -87, 32, 70, 108, 111, 114, 97]
>>> struct.pack("b"*len(a),*a)
'Caf\xc3\xa9 Flora'
>>> print struct.pack("b"*len(a),*a).decode('utf8')
Café Flora
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the little-used [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) to convert your input to a bytestring and then `decode` it with the UTF-8 codec:

```
import array
decoded = array.array('b', your_input).tostring().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: `ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)`

Comment: This gives me a ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)

Comment: @wim: Oh, huh. They have signed values in the input instead of unsigned. This won't work directly, then.

Comment: @wim: Decoding method switched to something that takes signed values.

Comment: In Python 3 `tostring()` was renamed to `tobytes()`, otherwise, this works great.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have in mind that a "string" in Python2 is not proper text, just a sequence of bytes in memory, which happens to map to characters when you "print" them - if the mapping of the intend characters in the byte sequence matches the one in the terminal, you will see properly formatted text.

If your terminal is not UTF-8, even if you get the proper byte-strign in memory, just printing it would show you the wrong results. That is why the extra "decode" step is needed at the end of the expression.

```
text = b''.join(chr(i if i > 0 else 256 + i) for i in array).decode('utf-8')
```

As your source encoded the numbers between 128 and 255 as negative numbers, we have the inline "if" operator to renormalize the value before calling "chr".

Just to be clear - you say "Since every character in the string I want is not necessarily represented by exactly 1 byte in the array," - So - what takes care of that if you use Python2.x strings, is the *terminal* anyway. If you want to deal with proper tet, after joining your numbers to a proper (byte) string, is to use the "decode" method - this is the part that will know about UTF-8 multi-byte encoded characters and give you back a (text) string object (an 'unicode' object in Python 2) - that will treat each character as an entity.

Comment: `i if i > 0 else 256 + i` can be written `i & 0xFF` too

Comment: It may work, although for semantic reasons, I would not recommend that. It abuses a side effect of the "&" operation just to make the number positive. Maybe the "most correct" way is @Joran's answer using struct  - but I am uncertain about the percformance of doing that. This way is the "thinking in strings" way.  :-)